# D3 Javascript, add text in group Arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i created a circular chart in D3, and i am trying to add text into the arc.
In the following piece of code, i managed to add the text as a title:

```
    svg.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(groupData[0])
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", groupArc)
    .attr("class", "groupArc")
    .data(nodes.filter(function(d) { return (d.key) && d.children; }))
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.company); })
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.company; })
```

it appears fine as a title, but a soon as i replace 'title' with 'text' or 'textPath', nothing shows up.

My knowlede of D3 is very limited and i have to deliver something while still learning it. Any help would by highly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: The SVG spec doesn't allow you to append `text` or `textPath` elements to `path` elements. You can group both with `g` elements.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i'll try to do that and post then the outcome

Comment: Lars, is this what you meant by grouping with g element:    

[code]

        var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")  
        .data(nodes.filter(function(d) { return (d.key) && d.children; }));  
     
        g.enter().append('group')   
       .attr('class', 'group');  
  
 g.selectAll('g.arc')  
        .data(function(d, i) { return d; })  
   .enter()  
   .append("path")  
   .attr("d", groupArc)  
   .attr("class", "groupArc")  
   .style("fill","red")  
   
 g.selectAll('text')  
    .append("text")  
    .text("ABC");  
  
[code]

Comment: sorry i dont manage to make the comment above formatted as a code

Comment: You can edit your question to add new information. And the group elements are `g` not `group`.